# Setup brownie to run certain test in a specific network

Tags: testing, unittesting, brownie

I am using brownie to run tests and right now my project is using two networks, `development` and `mainnet-fork`.
I have a test which only runs in `mainnet-fork` and I am trying to figure out a way to tell brownie that the test shouldn't be run when I execute:

```
brownie test -s --coverage --network development
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Unfortuantely this isn't easy to do right now with Brownie.  I've opened an issue to request the feature though! Feel free to leave feedback on the potential syntax. https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/810

Comment: @iamdefinitelyahuman can you answer with that link so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

As of `v1.12.0` this is possible using the [`require_network`](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests-pytest-fixtures.html#pytest.mark.require_network) marker:

> ```py
> pytest.mark.require_network(network_name)
> ```
>
> Mark a test so that it only runs if the active network is named `network_name`. This is useful when you have some tests intended for a local development environment and others for a forked mainnet.

For example, to make a test only execute when using a forked mainnet:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.require_network("mainnet-fork")
def test_almost_in_prod():
    pass
```

Comment: for some reason this still connects to the default network